# Slow process for IN clause in MySql SELECT Query that contain large numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query to fetch details from `table1`, which has this condition clause:

```
IN(number1,number2......
```

Up to 323 entries so far now. These numbers are the primary key of `table1`, which has been extracted from `table2` and passed into the IN condition clause.

Due to this my query slows down and takes 13 seconds to run. Is there any other way to overcome this? If I give some constant values (like PK id), the query works in usual time.

Comment: `I have written an query to fetch details` where is the query ?

Comment: share your existing query.

Comment: Please include the output of `EXPLAIN` on your query. It would also be useful to include the full query, as you might think you've narrowed it down, but it could be some other aspect of your query that makes it slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `LEFT JOIN`:

For example:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.numberfield = T2.numberfield
WHERE T2.someotherfield IS NOT NULL
```

This does the exact job of the query with `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

try below-

```
select a.* from table1 a join table2 b 
on a.parent_id=b.id;
```

Note: parent_id should be indexed in table 1 and assuming id will be prmary key of table b means already indexed.